# adding a spam flag statement on the community collumn on the right

Tags: feature-request

Would it not make life easier for moderators if a banner were displayed on the right requesting users to flag spam, making clear that six flags would get rid of the offending entry?

Comment: What would really help is a few extra nudges to read [/privileges](http://physics.stackexchange.com/privileges) every time one reaches the rep level for a new privilege.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't get much actual spam here, so even if all spam was flagged by the community, it would only relieve a *tiny* bit of the burden on moderators. While it certainly doesn't hurt to remind people to flag things, a notice about spam flagging specifically would be taking up space that I personally think is better used for other things.

<sup>(What would really help is having more 3k users casting close votes, when appropriate of course, so that when questions need to be closed, it can be done by the community without moderator intervention more often.)</sup>